# Вычисление значения по динамически заданной формуле

Tags: алгоритм, java

Такая задача: пользователь печатает на клавиатуре формулу, например x^2+x+1.
И эту формулу нужно как то воспринять, чтобы вычислять значения этой функции с разными значениями х.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно сделать? (желательно на Java)

В какую сторону копать ? :)

Comment: вариантов полно.. начни делать сам, выбери направление...

Comment: Приведите хотя бы 1 пример

Comment: [**Binary Expression Tree.**][1]

[1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_expression_tree

Comment: ну если ты формулу вводишь в консоль, то надо проверить остановку ввода и расчитать результат подставив в формулу значения - это общий алгоритм, конкретная реализация зависит от идеи

Comment: Посмотрите исходники утилиты bc из \*nix и изобразите что Вам надо из нее на Java.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказки. Остановился на синтаксическом анализе и Binary Expression Tree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Такой алгоритм разбора выражения называется *пАрсер* - это так к сведению.

Вам надо написать парсер разбирающий некую грамматическую конструкцию с заданной лексикой и проч. атрибутами языка/псевдоязыка. Грамматика вашего языка очевидна и понятна и на свете есть туча всяких парсеров разбирающих вашу грамматику. [Погуглите примерно так](https://www.google.com/#q=java+math+parser)

Если же у вас какая-то своя специфическая грамматика, то надо обратиться к генераторам парсеров. Превосходной исходной точкой будет служить [статья в википедии](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_parser_generators) о генераторах парсеров. В общем, смысл генератора парсера в том, чтобы по заданной грамматике языка (есть некий [стандарт описания грамматики](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing_expression_grammar)) сгенеририровать исходные тексты парсера.

**P.S.** Самостоятельное писание парсера считается дурным тоном, ну разве что с целью тренировки/обучения. Это очень хорошо проработанная отрасль знаний, в которой все уже доведено до конвейерного состояния. Наоборот, хороший специалист должен уметь пользоваться парочкой генераторов парсеров, чтобы в случае чего сварганить по бырому что-нибудь подходящее к случаю.

Comment: И все равно, сначала надо написать пару-тройку парсеров вручную (пусть с целью тренировки). 

Иначе при использовании генераторов будут оставаться непонятные моменты.

Comment: Ну разве же я против... Иначе конечно, сложно будет понимать что там наколбасит генератор. Я до сих пор помню свой первый парсер с польской инверсной записью :)

Comment: @Barmaley, вам особое спасибо. Ваши ответы всегда понятны и исчерпывающие :)

Answer (score 4):

[Простой разбор формул методом рекурсивного спуска на Java](http://habrahabr.ru/post/122397/).

Comment: Хорошая статья, а главное программа уже есть.

Comment: бггг, ссылка на мою статью :)

Comment: @shurik, вот интересно, как @wwvv отреагирует?

Comment: Спасибо за статью. @avp, а как я должен был отреагировать ? :)
Пробежался по статье и у меня возник вопрос, а не будут ли все эти махинации со строками слишком неэффективны ? Если мне понадобиться посчитать 10000 значений функции, не будет ли это слишком долго? 
Сейчас буду более подробно разбираться.

Comment: @www а вы попробуйте ;)

Comment: @wwvv, слишком медленно для кого? Человека со скоростью реакции поряда 0.1 сек?

У Вас странные представления о скорости работы компьютера с гигагерцовыми частотами.