# Считывание из строки

Tags: java

Здравствуйте.

Задача считать строку вида: 777 111 +
И вывести результат: 888

Объясните, пожалуйста, как правильно распарсить строку и/или считать все переменные отдельно.

Вот начал писать:

```
import java.io.*;
public class DefaultNamePP {

    public static void main(String[] args)  throws IOException {

    BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int x = bReader.read();
        int y = bReader.read();
        String z = bReader.readLine();
        calc(x, y, z);
    }

    public static void calc(int x, int y, String z) {
        if (z.equals("+")) {
            System.out.println(x+y);
            return;
        }
        if (z.equals("-")) {
            System.out.println(x-y);
            return;
        }
        if (z.equals("*")) {
            System.out.println(x*y);
            return;
        }
        if (z.equals("/")) {
            System.out.println(x/y);
            return;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Аналогичная [тема уже обсуждалась](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/142764/java-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B5). Рекомендую вчитаться и вкурить